# How do I resolve the need for a conditional dataLayer push within code, when Google recommends that dataLayer code be placed high in the source code?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am firing a dataLayer variable upon a form submit. The javascript code for this form submit is not at the top of the source code.

[Google recommends that we declare the dataLayer high in the source code.](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#thepits)

How do I resolve this? What are the potential consequences?

Assuming that I cannot make use Google Tag Manager's "Form Submit" variable and I need to send my custom variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant keyword in the documentation is "declare" - Google recommends that you initialise the variable high in the source code (one reason is that declaring the dataLayer after the GTM snippet would break GTM, because GTM overwrites the native push method of the dataLayer array. Also you want the values available at the page view event).

However if you add values dynamically to the dataLayer that's not a variable declaration, you are just using the push() method of the dataLayer array to add an object to the existing dataLayer array. That's fine, and it wouldn't really work any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Always use that code block to push your own values, without reseting / breaking GTM's initial `dataLayer` object AND ensure you don't have any unsolved dependency in your Javascript code:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; // creates a new Array only if it doesn't exists yet
dataLayer.push({
    'event':'myFormSubmit',
    'customVariable':'foo'
    });
```